# Convert CSS-Object to Style Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typescript

Sometimes I'm forced to add CSS styles to the DOM programmatically (if you need a reason: imagine writing a small ui widget that comes with its own styling but is supposed to only consist of one single *.js file for easier handling). In this case I prefer defining the style in my script code with object notation instead of one large string that mixes rules, properties, and markup.

```
var thumbHoverStyle = {
    "background-color": "rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5)",
    "cursor": "pointer"
};
```

versus

```
var thumbHoverStyle = "<style> .thumb:hover { background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5); cursor: pointer; } </style>";
```

Such a css-object can easily be used with [JQuery's .css() function](http://api.jquery.com/css/), but the trouble starts as soon as I want to style a [css pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) (in my example :hover). In this case I can't use the JQuery `.css()` function and I fall back to inserting a corresponding style tag into my DOM.

```
var thumbHoverStyleTag = toStyleTag( { ".thumb:hover": thumbHoverStyle } );
_root.append(thumbHoverStyleTag);
```

I googled and stackoverflowed but could not find a utility function that converts my css-object into a style tag.
In the end I wrote my own function (and I will probably provide it as an answer to this question), but I still want to know if there is a library function for this.
What is the most elegant method to accomplish this?

**Edit**

My implementation in TypeScript:

```
function appendPxIfNumber(value: any): string
{
    return (typeof value === "number") ? "" + value + "px" : value;
}

function toStyleTag(rulesObj: any)
{
    var combinedRules: string = "";
    for (var selector in rulesObj)
    {
        var cssObject = rulesObj[selector];
        var combinedProperties = "";
        for (var prop in cssObject) {
            var value = cssObject[prop];
            combinedProperties += `${prop}: ${appendPxIfNumber(value)};` + "\n";
        }
        combinedRules += ` ${selector} {${combinedProperties}}` + "\n";
    }
    return $(`<style>${combinedRules}</style>`);
}
```

Usage example:

```
var styleTag = toStyleTag( { ".thumb": thumbStyle, ".thumb:hover": thumbHoverStyle } );
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a working example which works with the origin style object:
I'll convert the `JSON`into `CSS`. and define a target which should be styled Keep in mind there is no selector which should be styled... So I added a `targetSelector`.

```
var targetSelector='.thumb:hover',
    styleObj = {
      "background-color": "rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5)",
      "cursor": "pointer"
    },

    // Convert the JSON into CSS
    styleTagContent = JSON.stringify(styleObj,null,'\t')
                          .replace(/"/g,'')
                          .replace(/,\n/g,';')
                          .replace(/\}/g, ';}')  



  $('<style>'+targetSelector+styleTagContent+'</style>').appendTo('head');
```

Here's a working [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/n2BnDCqTdvhLdwXIjGTw?p=preview) to see how it works.

Comment: Oh nice, I haven't thought of using `JSON stringify` to convert my css-object into a css string.

Comment: Your method will strip quote of `a:before{content: '123'}`

Comment: Single quotes aren’t valid JSON and I guess it’s probably parsed then as a number. But not sure actually.

Answer (score 1):

The methodology behind my function `toStyleTag()` is that it first iterates over `styleTag` using a [for...in statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and checking if `styleTag` [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) of the `selector`. I then [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array returned by executing [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on the object, `styleTag[selector]`, which I [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the `accumulator` by joining the `currentValue` (the property) and the `styleTag[selector][currentValue]]` (the rule) to be `:` separated. Doing so lets `styles` become an array of strings that are in the form of `property: rule`. This is now the format we need to use [insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule), which we use this to insert the new CSS rule into the current style sheet. Notice that I am grabbing length of the `cssRules` to find the index + 1, so that we can insert this new rule at the very end of our style sheet to ensure it is not overwritten.

```js
var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];

function toStyleTag(styleTag) {
  for(var selector in styleTag) {
    if(styleTag.hasOwnProperty(selector)) {
      let styles = Object.keys(styleTag[selector]).reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
        return accumulator.concat([currentValue, styleTag[selector][currentValue]].join(':'));
      }, []);
      styleSheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + styles.join(';') + '}', styleSheet.cssRules.length);
    }
  }
}

var thumbHoverStyle = {
  'background-color': 'rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5)',
  'cursor': 'pointer'
};

toStyleTag({ '.thumb:hover': thumbHoverStyle });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. My `toStyleTag()` function is similar, iterating over the input with a `for..in` loop and concatenating the parts one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to have another go at this, because it's a fascinating problem.

Here's the native javascript solution I put together:

```js
var thumbStyle = {
    "width" : "100px",
    "height" : "100px",
    "text-align" : "center",
    "line-height" : "100px",
    "background-color": "rgb(211, 211, 211)"
};

var thumbHoverStyle = {
    "color" : "rgb(255,255,255)",
    "background-color": "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "cursor": "pointer"
};

var dynamicStyle = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(dynamicStyle);
var dynamicStyleSheet = dynamicStyle.sheet;

function addStyles(selector, cssStyleObject) {
    var properties = Object.keys(cssStyleObject);
    properties.forEach(function(property){
        var value = cssStyleObject[property];
      
        var dynamicRule = selector + ' {' + property + ': ' + value + ';}';
      
        dynamicStyleSheet.insertRule(dynamicRule, dynamicStyleSheet.cssRules.length);
    });
}

// Add styles dynamically by stating a selector and the name of a CSS Style Object

addStyles('div', thumbStyle);
addStyles('div:hover', thumbHoverStyle);
```

```html
<div>Hover Me</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if it really matters but this way you would produce and add a new rule for each property that is part of the style instead of one rule with n properties.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - can you explain again, please? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand your resulting css would look like: `.foo {color: red;} .foo {background-color: white;} .foo {margin-left: 2px;} .foo {margin-right: 4px;}` instead of `.foo {color: red; background-color: white; margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 4px;}`

Comment: Ah, yes, I see - and I take your point. Fairly straightforward to fix though. You can move the declaration of `var dynamicRule = selector + ' {'` above the `forEach` loop and then loop through `dynamicRule +=  property + ': ' + value + '; '`

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to:

- add a `thumbHoverStyle` CSS object on `mouseover()`; and
- replace it with a `thumbDefaultStyle` CSS object on `mouseout()`

```js
var thumbStyle = {
    "width" : "100px",
    "height" : "100px",
    "text-align" : "center",
    "line-height" : "100px",
    "background-color": "rgb(211, 211, 211)"
};

var thumbHoverStyle = {
    "color" : "rgb(255,255,255)",
    "background-color": "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "cursor": "pointer"
};

var thumbDefaultStyle = {
    "color" : "rgb(0,0,0)",
    "background-color": "rgb(211, 211, 211)",
    "cursor": "default"
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div').css(thumbStyle);

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

        if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')) {

            $('div').mouseover(function(){
                $(this).css(thumbHoverStyle);
            });

            $('div').mouseout(function(){
                $(this).css(thumbDefaultStyle);
            });
        }

        else {

            $('div').mouseover(function(){
                $(this).css(thumbDefaultStyle);
            });

            $('div').mouseout(function(){
                $(this).css(thumbDefaultStyle);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div, button {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 24px;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hover Me</div>
<input type="checkbox" />Activate New Hover Behaviour
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposed solution. But I have additional reasons to find the converter function described in my question. The :hover class was but one example. And I would rather let the browser's rendering engine handle the hover visual states of elements, than writing mouseIn/mouseOut handler code to simulate css :hover.